# In Git, is there a way identify in a commit range the files that only had updates in a specific line range?

Tags: git

In a long and complicated history of changes, a few hundreds of files had their information header updated in an undesired way. The complication is that the update is correct for one subset of the updated files, but incorrect for another. Both subsets are large and overlap exists.

One way to identify whether a file has been incorrectly updated is to identify whether it has had any change done outside of the first 20 lines.

Is there a method in Git to query the change history and obtain a list of files in which the update type is add or modified and it took place in the first 20 lines? Is there a way to revert the changes for only these files?

Comment: You can `git blame` the files and inspect the timestamp and commit info on each first 20 lines.

Comment: @Niloct Can this be automated, e.g. from a list of files, use git blame to filter, or is it a manual process. There are several hundred of files that need to be inspected otherwise.

Comment: Are you using Linux ? If so a simple bash script can do it.

Comment: Do you need to spot this "modifications happened only in first 20 lines" condition on each individual commit in a range ? or on the global diff between a starting point and the end point ?

Comment: I don't have time to cook a complete script at the moment, but looking at `git diff <start> <end> -U0`, and checking whether the range lines (lines looking like `@@ -x,n +y,k @@`) have either (x+n) or (y+k) greater than 20 should indicate that there was indeed a modification outside of the header block.

Comment: If you need to inspect individual commits : scan `git log -p -U0 <start>..<end>` instead

Comment: @LeGEC Global difference is sufficient. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @LeGEC regarding the range lines of the diff, I was thinking the same thing initially but decided against it because I was worried that it wouldn't catch everything, for example I think deleting the first 10 lines, and also inserting 5 lines at line 19, would pass that test, but perhaps shouldn't, and I couldn't convince myself that the 4 numbers alone would be sufficient to always get it right. I ended up going with just diffing the tails of the files after the first 20 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Here's a working algorithm:

1. Identify a commit before all the changes. Let's call that commit `X`, and let's call your current state `main`.
2. For each file in question, print out the the version of the file at commit `X`, skipping the first 20 lines.
3. For each file in question, print out the the version of the file at commit `main`, skipping the first 20 lines.
4. Diff 2 and 3. If you get output, the file was changed outside of the first 20 lines.

Here's a working example using Bash which identifies all files *modified* between commits `X` and `main`, and tells you which files have no changes outside of the first 20 lines:

`CompareFiles.sh X main 21`

**CompareFiles.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

startCommit=$1
endCommit=$2
numLines=$3

if [ -z "$numLines" ] ; then
    echo "Missing argument! Usage: $0 <startCommit> <endCommit> <numLines>"
    exit 1
fi

git diff $startCommit $endCommit --name-only --diff-filter=M | while read line
do
    if [[ ! $(diff <(git show $startCommit:"$line" | tail +$numLines) <(git show $endCommit:"$line" | tail +$numLines)) ]] ; then
      echo "File: $line has NO other changes."    
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with git diff, like:
`git diff ^hash_from hash_to -G"regex_to_find_wrong_header" --name-only`

for example:
`git diff ^bac976e6 afa99167 -G"some_unique_text" --name-only`

For -G option please check the [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Gltregexgt) documentation.
Note that first commit from which you want to start searching has a caret (^) in front.

Altohough it does not checks the first 20 lines of files, it should solve your problem.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, because the condition that detects it's the incorrect header is that only the header lines were modified. So there needs to be some verification that no other line except for the header range was modified.